# React bootstrap modal doesn't completely close after i click away or even from the close button

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a modal in a react component and when I open it, it does not completely close with any sort of action clicking away or even hitting the close button by completely I mean it removes the backdrop but the modal stays in screen(I will attach a screenshot for that)
[image: This is what it looks like when I click away or click the close button][image: My react code]
[image: My modal code]

Comment: Be sure to pass the function 'closeModal' to the 'onHide' property of the Modal component

Comment: @MaCadiz same issue

Comment: In that case I ask you to provide a minimal code in a sandbox that reproduces this please, if it's possible

Comment: @MaCadiz i figured it out, it seems that my button in the modal header mess something somehow, and when i removed it it worked, thank you soo much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems that my button in the modal header was messing something up somehow. When I removed it, it worked!